# Add columns to specific rows in a list of data frames from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I want to add two columns next to the headers of the list mentioned below (except the 1st data frame).

Structure of the list of data frames `multidf` where I want to add the columns

```
structure(list(`0` = structure(list(X01.04.2020 = 0:1, Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH"), Position = c("--", "--"), Price = c("--", "--"), Mark.to.Market = c(1000000L, 1000000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), `1` = structure(list(X02.04.2020 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH", "FUTURES", "VXc1", "Total"), Position = c("--", "--", "500", "-5931", "Buys:"), Price = c("--", "--", "2516", "47", "1"), Mark.to.Market = c("999231", "509866", "1258250", "-279795", "Sells:"), Position.prior = c(NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L), Transaction = c("", "", "500", "-5931", "TC spent:"), TC.spent = c(NA, NA, 629L, 140L, 769L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), `2` = structure(list(X03.04.2020 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH", "FUTURES", "VXc1", "Total"), Position = c("--", "--", "505", "-6206", "Buys:"), Price = c("--", "--", "2483", "45", "1"), Mark.to.Market = c("995708", "508078", "1253789", "-278805", "Sells:"), Position.prior = c(NA, NA, 500L, -5931L, 1L), Transaction = c("", "", "5", "-275", "TC spent:"), TC.spent = c(NA, NA, 6L, 6L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), `3` = structure(list(X06.04.2020 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH", "FUTURES", "VXc1", "Total"), Position = c("--", "--", "522", "-7352", "Buys:"), Price = c("--", "--", "2644", "42", "1"), Mark.to.Market = c("1096915", "559989", "1380429", "-307130", "Sells:"), Position.prior = c(NA, NA, 505L, -6206L, 1L), Transaction = c("", "", "17", "-1146", "TC spent:"), TC.spent = c(NA, NA, 22L, 24L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), `4` = structure(list(X07.04.2020 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH", "FUTURES", "VXc1", "Total"), Position = c("--", "--", "514", "-6863", "Buys:"), Price = c("--", "--", "2642", "44", "1"), Mark.to.Market = c("1079069", "550870", "1357988", "-302144", "Sells:"), Position.prior = c(NA, NA, 522L, -7352L, 1L), Transaction = c("", "", "-8", "489", "TC spent:"), TC.spent = c(NA, NA, 11L, 11L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), `5` = structure(list(X08.04.2020 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA), Asset = c("PORTFOLIO", "CASH", "FUTURES", "VXc1", "Total"), Position = c("--", "--", "524", "-7521", "Buys:"), Price = c("--", "--", "2735", "42", "1"), Mark.to.Market = c("1138189", "580800", "1433140", "-318702", "Sells:"), Position.prior = c(NA, NA, 514L, -6863L, 1L), Transaction = c("", "", "10", "-658", "TC spent:"), TC.spent = c(NA, NA, 14L, 14L, 28L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = list(`cumsum(!grepl("\\S", txt))` = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

This is the expected result
[image: Reproducible Example]

Structure of data frame `df3` (the last two columns from reproducible example) that needs to be added to the list of data frames as shown above

```
structure(c("DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "FLAT", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
```

I have used the following code to get the list of data frames `multidf` and data frame `df3`

```
#Load the two input files in a data frame
df1 <- read.csv("SP500Preds_20210202.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("VIXPredPerfectForesight_20210213.csv")
#Extract and combine the required items to be loaded in final output
df3 <- cbind(df1[, c(3)], df2[, c(3)])
#Load the file that needs to be updated
txt <- readLines("ProcessedTrades.csv")
multidf <- by(txt, cumsum(!grepl("\\S", txt)), 
  FUN = function(x) read.csv(text = x, strip.white = TRUE))
```

In order to get the expected result, I have used the following code

```
multidf[-1] <- Map(cbind, multidf[-1], asplit(df3, 1))
```

I am getting the following error

> multidf[-1] <- Map(cbind, multidf[-1], asplit(df3, 1))
> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 2

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

adding reproducible examples of CSV files below

SP500Preds_20210202.csv or `df1`

```
structure(list(date = c("04/06/19", "05/06/19", "06/06/19", "07/06/19", "10/06/19", "11/06/19"), prediction_for_date = c("11/6/2019", "12/6/2019", "13/06/19", "14/06/19", "17/06/19", "18/06/19"), Predictions = c("DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN", "FLAT")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

VIXPredPerfectForesight_20210213.csv or `df2`

```
structure(list(date = c(20190604L, 20190605L, 20190606L, 20190607L, 20190610L, 20190611L), X1.Day.Pred = c("DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN"), X5.Day.Pred = c("UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, as your .csv files are not accessible it's not possible to run or test your code.

Comment: @EmilyKothe have added minimal reproducible examples. Hope that helps in running the code.

Comment: Please consider our guidelines on reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you for helping me out on this. have made the changes using `dput`
hope this helps now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 6 elements (`data.frame`) in the `list` `multidf` and there are 6 rows in the `matrix` 'df3'.  So, if the intention is to create two new columns in each of the `list` elements

```
multidf2 <- Map(cbind, multidf, lapply(asplit(df3, 1), as.list))
```

---

Or with `apply`

```
multidf2 <- Map(cbind, multidf, apply(df3, 1, as.list))
```

---

If we need to create only two blank columns with column names as in 'df3' rows

```
multidf2 <-  Map(function(x, y) {x[y] <- ''; x}, multidf, asplit(df3, 1))
```